# Unable to find pdb file

Tags: c#, .net, xna-4.0

I am new to C# and was working on a small game using the XNA framework when these errors started to show up. Using Google I was able to load the symbols for projects other than XNA framework extensions. However, this didn't fix the problem.

The project just show up first build succeeded and then a sound of windows error show up and the output field is filled with the messages below.

> 'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Abdullah Akmal\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SpriteDrawing\SpriteDrawing\SpriteDrawing\bin\x86\Debug\SpriteDrawing.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpriteDrawing.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpriteDrawing.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpriteDrawing.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpriteDrawing.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpriteDrawing.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpriteDrawing.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'SpriteDrawing.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpriteDrawing.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   The program '[6200] SpriteDrawing.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[6200] SpriteDrawing.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Is `SpriteDrawing.exe` your program? If so, are you building it in Debug so you get a PDB?

Answer (score 0):

I had problem similar to yours dealing with xna once and solved it, see my answer to this question:
[can't open vs2010 csproj file in vs2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050689/cant-open-vs2010-csproj-file-in-vs2012)
hope it helps.